# RegEx for jsDoc comments

Tags: javascript, regex, jsdoc

Can't find any usable RegExp example to match all jsDoc comment blocks within a text file.

Basically, it needs to find all blocks that satisfy the following rules:

- Starts with `/**`, followed by one or more line breaks
- Ends with `*/`
- Within the block there can be anything, including code examples and HTML.

I tried the code from [jsdoc-regex](https://github.com/neogeek/jsdoc-regex), but it didn't work:

```
/[^\S\r\n]*\/(?:\*{2})([\W\w]+?)\*\/([\W\w]+?)?(?=\s+\/\*{1,2}|$)/g;
```

**NOTE:**

I am parsing generic text files, not necessarily JavaScript, so I can't use  JS parsers like Esprima.

**UPDATE:**

To rephrase my question, I'm stuck trying to define a RegEx rule that says the expression must end with `*/`, while there can be anything prior to it (within the block), i.e. by anything in this case means anything except `*/`.

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to you the answer by **@m93a**, his implementation has become a valuable addition to [decomment](https://github.com/vitaly-t/decomment), option [ignore](https://github.com/vitaly-t/decomment#optionsignore--regexp--regexp).

Comment: could you use a js parser like esprisima?

Comment: @DanielA.White no, i can't use additional parsers for this, I can only use a RegExp in my example, which is generic, and effectively can match anything. jsDoc is just one example that I got stuck with.

Comment: Can you tell us a little more of what you've tried? It seems that you're hoping someone will just give you the answer rather than trying to learn RegExp and trying to implement your own. This isn't what this site is about.

Comment: @EzequielMuns I have copied the RegExp from the link I provided from the beginning. That's what I tried, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Build your expression: Tutorial

1. `/ /` – empty expression
2. `/` **`\/\*\*`** `/` – match `/**` (escaped)
3. `/` `\/\*\*` **`\s*\n`** `/` – followed by a line break (whitespace chars may be preceding)
4. `/` `\/\*\*` `\s*\n` **`\*\/`** `/`  – match `*/` (escaped)
5. `/` `\/\*\*` `\s*\n` **`(` `)`** `\*\/` `/`  – add a group
6. `/` `\/\*\*` `\s*\n` `(` **`[^\*]`** `)` `\*\/` `/`  – the group may consist of anything but `*`
7. `/` `\/\*\*` `\s*\n` `(` `[^\*]` **`|` `(` `)`** `)` `\*\/` `/`  – or another group
8. `/` `\/\*\*` `\s*\n` `(` `[^\*]` `|` `(` **`\*`** `)` `)` `\*\/` `/`  – where there is an `*`
9. `/` `\/\*\*` `\s*\n` `(` `[^\*]` `|` `(` `\*` **`(?!\/)`** `)` `)` `\*\/` `/`  – but isn't followed by a `/`
10. `/` `\/\*\*` `\s*\n` `(` `[^\*]` `|` `(` `\*` `(?!\/)` `)` `)` **`*`** `\*\/` `/`  – repeat the whole thing
11. `/\/\*\*\s*\n([^\*]|(\*(?!\/)))*\*\//` – **Tadaa!** Beautiful, isn't it?

Comment: What about the first requirement where it says: `...,followed by one or more line breaks`?

Comment: @vitaly-t Good point, didn't read the question properly. Fixed now.

Comment: thanks to you, this has made a valuable addition to [decomment](https://github.com/vitaly-t/decomment), option [ignore](https://github.com/vitaly-t/decomment#optionsignore--regexp--regexp).

Comment: @m93a, It works great for most cases. However, sometimes, the comment block ends with `**/` instead of `*/`. In that case, it gets stuck. You must hit ^C to exit the process. An example of code where I have this issue: `/**
 * My Component (new line here)
**/
export default class MyClass extends React.Component { }`

Comment: @David Yes, there actually was a bug, thanks for spotting it! Now the expression successfully ignores any `*` that aren't followed by a `/`. Note that it still doesn't work for your string, because the OP specifically requested that the `/**` sequence has to be followed by a newline. To make it work for you, you have to remove the step #3.

Comment: Thanks @m93a! it works perfectly for me as well. I also needed the `\n`, it was just removed by StackOverflow when I wrote the comment.

Comment: @m93a is there to accomplish this without the look-ahead. It is not supported in Rust Regex

Comment: @IkechukwuEze Instead of the look-ahead, you could match “anything but slash” using `[^\/]`. Also, this will probably have better performance than the expression I've written. Try it out and be sure to let me know whether it worked ;)

Comment: @m93a exactly what I found out. I also added it as an answer, I can remove it if it's not necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @m39a's answer. If you are using a language or Regex library that doesn't support look-around. You can use this: 
`\/\*\*\s*\n([^\*]|\*[^\/])*\*\/`

Check it out at Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/TMr78R/1