# Get JSDoc comments Node js

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

I use PHP's [reflectionclass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php) to write my own API documentation generator where it generates Documentation for some functions and classes by getting the Doc Comments attached to them and parsing it.

Now I need to do the same in Node.js. Is there a built-in JavaScript function that can find JSDoc comments of a specific identifier? I mean without having to write code to manually parse the source code as in [this JSDoc regex question asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905181/regex-for-jsdoc-comments)

I need something just like in this PHP example

```
<?php
/** 
* A test class
*
* @param  foo bar
* @return baz
*/
class TestClass { }

$rc = new ReflectionClass('TestClass');
var_dump($rc->getDocComment())
?>
```

**Output:**

```
string(55) "/** 
* A test class
*
* @param  foo bar
* @return baz
*/"
```

Comment: Sorry, I have delete my answer, because I didn't understand the question.

Comment: it's fine, you didn't have to. Thank you for trying to help anyway :)